# Mysql - Time dimension table

Tags: mysql, dimension

I created a time dimension table and I'm trying to fill it but it gives error. I couldn't solve it.

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE PROCEDURE timedimbuild ()"

```
delimiter //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS timedimbuild;
CREATE PROCEDURE timedimbuild ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_full_date DATETIME;
    DELETE FROM timedim;
    SET v_full_date = '2009-03-01 00:00:00';
    WHILE v_full_date < '2009-03-02 00:00:00' DO
        INSERT INTO timedim (
            fulltime ,
            hour ,
            minute ,
            second ,
            ampm
        ) VALUES (
            TIME(v_full_date),
            HOUR(v_full_date),
            MINUTE(v_full_date),
            SECOND(v_full_date),
            DATE_FORMAT(v_full_date,'%p')
        );
        SET v_full_date2 = DATE_ADD(v_full_date2, INTERVAL 1 SECOND);
    END WHILE;
END;

//
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the delimiter

```
delimiter //
```

you have to use the new one then. So instead of `;` use `//`

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS timedimbuild//
```